# Showing different states in a Spell-dataset using SPSS Syntax

Tags: syntax, spss

I have a Dataset which involves different states for a person ("Number) and the length of a state. my Goal is to Define the Start and End Date for each State in a new Variable.

**What I got:**

Number----Start date----End Date-----State
24-------01-Jan-1975----26-Mar-1975-----1 
24-------10-Jul-1975----31-Dec-1975-----1 
24-------01-Jul-1981----03-Oct-1981----11
24-------25-Aug-1983----31-Dec-1983-----1 
24-------01-Jan-1983----31-Aug-1984-----1

**What i need**

Number----Start date----End Date-----State-----Begin-------End
24-------01-Jan-1975----26-Mar-1975-----1 -----01-Jan-1975---31-Dec-1975
24-------10-Jul-1975----31-Dec-1975-----1 -----01-Jan-1975---31-Dec-1975
24-------01-Jul-1981----03-Oct-1981----11------01-Jul-1981---03-Oct-1981
24-------25-Aug-1983----31-Dec-1983-----1 -----25-Aug-1983---31-Aug-1984
24-------01-Jan-1983----31-Aug-1984-----1 -----25-Aug-1983---31-Aug-1984

I aceted around with Aggregate command but did not succeed

Comment: Is "01-Jan-1983" as beginning date an error?

Answer (score 0):

Right now you can't use `aggregate` because there is no clear `break` variable set. , The following syntax first creates such a variable and then uses it in aggregation (Assuming the data is pre-sorted and that those dates are well defined date-time variables):

```
compute brkvar=1.
if $casenum>1 brkvar=lag(brkvar) + (number<>lag(number) or state<>lag(state)).
aggregate /outfile=* mode=addvariables /break = brkvar 
          /STbegin=min(StartDate) /STend=max(EndDate).
```

Comment: Oh thanks a lot. That is very helpful. One final question: How do I have to change the code if I have more than one casenumbers? Like After that there is Number 101 with a few cases and then number 201 and so on?

Comment: The syntax accounts for that in principal - the `brkvar` changes every time you have a new `state` for the same `number` or a new `number`.

Comment: Thats weird. In my dataset it does not work this way. In my Dataset the code writes a brkvar Value for the first case with a new Number and then it creates missings for the brkvar value. It also writes the STbegin and the STend that was found in this first case with a new number.

Comment: Edit: I understand this now. It happens wenn the state variables has a missing value.

Comment: If you edit your post to add the possibility of missing state, and explain what should happen in that case, I can edit the solution accordingly. In any case a simple solution would be, before you start, to `recode state (miss=999). ` (or some different specific "non value") so the missing values don't break the numbering.